# How to send images to a projector using my own c/c++, OpenCV based software?

Tags: opencv, projector, screen-projection

What I want is, I want to send a image to a projector using my own software which is written in C/C++, OpenCv languages. So, is there any library that support this functionality. 
Actually, I am working on a 3D scanner, so for a 3D scanner I have to send images to a projector for displaying onto the object, and for real-time I have to send images directly from my own software for processing further.

Same like OpenCV which can initialize any camera and have ability to capture.
Is there any way in OpenCV, that I can initialize the projector and send images to projector for displaying using my own way?

Comment: imshow() them on screen, and the OS will take care of the rest. Sending them in any other way implies writing your own drivers or video card access API, which is a bit awkward.

Comment: OpenCV library focuses more on the processing of image signals. Except some minimal functionality to display an image and some GUI features; it does not contain much on display part. Trying to run a projector from OpenCV is a far fetched thing!!!

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to find a way in OpenCV to do my task.